limit of mutual coupling
The two inductors are in parallel and are coupled magnetically.  The equivalent inductance of the arrangement is,
$$L_{eq}=\frac{L_1L_2-M^2}{L_1+L_2+2M}$$
This would obviously be zero when \$M=\sqrt{L_1L_2}\$.  So the equivalent would be a direct short.
What is the practical upper limit for \$M\$?

The image is from Figure 13.4f of Basic Engineering Circuit Analysis, 3rd ed., by J. David Irwin.

The only limit is the amount of money you're willing to spend on that transformer.


What is the practical upper limit for M?

The maximum theoretical value for the mutual inductance of two inductors is
$$M = \sqrt{L_1L_2}$$
Practically, one can get quite close to this value.
